# Is Spring Data JPA safe against SQL injection

Tags: database, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, sql-injection

I am trying to find information about Spring Security JPA and if methods like `.save()` are protected from sql injection.

For instance I have object `Customer.` that I want to persist to my database.
I am using CustomerRepository Spring implementation to operate on that entity.
Customer's constructor is using parameters from the user. When everything is staged I am invoking `.save()`. Is this safe against sql injection or Should I do the check up first?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`.save()` is safe, only the usage of native queries is vulnerable.

```
List results = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select * from Customer where name = " + name).getResultList();
```

You can make native queries safe also, if you use a parameter.

```
Query sqlQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select * from Customer where name = ?", Customer.class);
List results = sqlQuery.setParameter(1, "John Doe").getResultList();
```

Comment: so for instance if Customer object has field name, and it is set to be a string: Select * from Customer where name = 'test' and i use save() method, nothing wrong with table wiill happen?

Comment: The JDBC driver will escape this data appropriately before the query is executed;

Comment: The problem here is when String name = "'Cosmin' or name='Jhon'"

Comment: is CrudRepository methods like .save() .delete() is safe for sql injection ?

Comment: @jklee Do you have a reference of your argument, it seems to be hard to find it.